# Can I create a system wide custom signature in Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

How do I create a system wide email signature in Office 365 that is individually customized for every user?

I know this was possible in on premises Exchange though the transport rules but can this be done in Office 365?

Comment: What's your game?

Comment: Is this really system administration ?

Comment: @joeqwerty Haven't you heard? The price of hosting blogs is steadily going up but Server Fault has remained free.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System wide custom signatures are possible to implement in Office 365. They are basically a transport rule for exchange.

To configure create Disclaimers using Transport Rules, you need to open up the Exchange Admin Center of Office 365.
Now navigate to the Mail Flow section to create your first rule.
Creating a Default Disclaimer that Applies to all Users.

To have a custom message use variables which will pull from the Azure Active Directory. Here is an example:

%%displayname%%
%%title%%
%%company%%
%%street%%
%%city%%, %%state%% %%zipcode%%

For more information see the Exchange Online Documentation on disclaimers and signatures here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600437(v=exchg.150).aspx